# clang: Use QHash<K,T> instead of QMap<K,T> when K is a pointer

Tags: c++, qt, clang-static-analyzer

There is a warning

> Use QHash<K,T> instead of QMap<K,T> when K is a pointer [clazy-qmap-with-pointer-key]

produced by clang. But I couldn't google out an explanation on why QHash is preferable... (In my case I have less than 100 pointers). Are there any clarifications about that warning?

Comment: What kind of pointer is `K`? A smart pointer?

Comment: no, just a pointer to a structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Clazy, that is a tool (actually a compiler plugin) that helps clang to "diggest" qt semantics better when compiling...

clazy has some rules, and the one you are violating is the Level 0:

> qmap-with-pointer-key

they document the reason as following:

> QMap has the particularity of sorting it's keys, but sorting by memory address makes no sense. Use QHash instead, which provides faster lookups.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the reason is that normally the ordering of pointers is irrelevant (except if they are pointers inside the same array) thus a red-black tree map is slower without providing any serious benefit.